# How can I change the value of a variable inside an if statement in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to change the value of a PHP variable inside an if statement.

---

### What my files look like:

My main file looks like this:

```
include_once '/css/colors.php';

// Check if contrast mode is on
if($_GET['cm'] == 1){
    $priColor = '#333';
}
```

My colors.php file looks like this:

```
$priColor = '#fff';
```

My request looks like this btw:

```
index.php?cm=1
```

---

### What I know:

I know the if statement is being accessed, 'cause if I throw in `echo: 'test';` it says `test` in the document.

---

### What I think is wrong:

It looks like I'm not able to change a variable inside an if statement that's declared in another document. But why? And what's a possible solution?

Thanks in advance! ^^

Comment: Should work. Where and what is the problem?

Comment: What output you get?

Comment: If you look at $priColor  what do you get right after the if?  Are you trying to use it right there?

Comment: I got it! I was requesting the normal page with ?cm=1 but used it inside a stylesheet that I didn't request with a parameter. So that's why... Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to change css property via jquery, it would be something like this:

```
echo <script>$("#example").css("color", "red")</script>;
```

Or if you want to do via php you have to set the variable global, like that:

```
$GLOBALS['priColor'] = '#333';
```